# android webview not able to add Custom font?

Tags: android, fonts, webview

I'am not able to change webview Font at all , I've tried every example here the custom font wont work

my custom font path is

```
assets/fonts/neu.ttf
```

I've changed the ttf font many times to check if its work or not all fonts working fine with TextView by when i attempt to use them on webview they wont work

this is my `webview` Header

```
String global_css =  "@font-face {font-family: 'feast';src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/neu.ttf');format('truetype');}"+ 
                         "body,html{font-family: 'feast';color : #000000;font-size: 10pt; word-wrap: break-word;"
                         + "-webkit-touch-callout:none;"
                         + "-webkit-user-select:none;"
                         + "-khtml-user-select:none;"
                         + "-moz-user-select:none;"
                         + "-ms-user-select:none;"
                         + "user-select:none;"
                         + "-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);} "+
                        "img{margin : 2px;} "+ 
                        "img.youtbe_img{padding: 2px;border : 1px solid #dfdfdf;background-color : #ebebeb;margin : 3px;}"+
                        "a {text-decoration: none;color: #0066CC}"+
                        "fieldset{word-wrap:break-word;font-size: 9pt;border : 1px solid #e6e6e6;margin : 10px 0;color: #636363;background-color: #f6f6f6;padding:5px;}"+
                        "legend{font-size: 9pt;border : 1px solid #e6e6e6;padding: 4px 5px;background-color : #ffffff;color : #6a6a6a;}"+
                        "img,legend,fieldset{-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;}"+
                        "img.effect_me{-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #b2b2b2;box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #b2b2b2;}";


    return "<style type=\"text/css\">"+global_css+"</style>";
```

and the Webview

```
holder.message.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,aHtml.output(post.pagehtml),"text/html","UTF-8",null);
```

I've tried removeing `file:///android_asset` and `format('truetype')`

still not working

any advice will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
holder.message.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",aHtml.output(post.pagehtml),"text/html","UTF-8",null);
```

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers Still not working? So why you accept the answer!!